# ClosedChannelException when trying to write to Cloud Bigtable in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-bigtable

I'm trying to write to cloud bigtable in my app engine servlet. I copied the BigTableHelper from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/managed-vm-gae/gae-bigtable-hello/src/main/java/com.example.cloud.bigtable.helloworld/BigtableHelper.java, and in my servlet I simply did the following.

```
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
      throws IOException {
    try (Table t = BigtableHelper.getConnection().getTable(BigtableHelper.TEST_TABLE)) {
      Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes("row1"));
      put.addColumn(BigtableHelper.RAW_UPDATE_FAMILY, BigtableHelper.RAW_UPDATE_QUALIFIER,
              Bytes.toBytes("testdata"));
      t.put(put);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      log("writeToBigtable", e);
    }
}
```

The put failed with error.

java.io.IOException: Failed to perform operation. Operation='put', projectId='myprojectid', tableName='test_table', rowKey='row1'   at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableTable.put(BigtableTable.java:288)    at  ...

Caused by: com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN    at io.grpc.stub.Calls.getUnchecked(Calls.java:117)  at io.grpc.stub.Calls.blockingUnaryCall(Calls.java:129)     at com.google.cloud.bigtable.grpc.BigtableGrpcClient.mutateRow(BigtableGrpcClient.java:210)     at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableTable.put(BigtableTable.java:285)    ... 32 more

Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN  at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:428)   at io.grpc.stub.Calls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(Calls.java:324)   at io.grpc.ChannelImpl$CallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$3.run(ChannelImpl.java:402)    at io.grpc.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)  ... 1 more

Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

BigtableHelper.getConnection() didn't throw an exception, I assume the it connect successfully. Is there anything wrong with the put statement? What could cause this problem? Thanks!

Comment: I'd need to see both your RAW_UPDATE_FAMILY & RAW_UPDATE_QUALIFIER to help.  In the mean time, you might take a look at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/blob/master/java/managed-vm-gae/gae-bigtable-hello/src/main/java/com.example.cloud.bigtable.helloworld/JsonServlet.java in the doPost() method.

Comment: They are defined as follows  

public static final byte[] RAW_UPDATE_FAMILY = Bytes.toBytes("u");
public static final byte[] RAW_UPDATE_QUALIFIER = Bytes.toBytes("r");

Comment: I presume you created the table w/ u as a column family?

Comment: Yes. I created the table with "u" as a column family.

Comment: It really looks like you closed your connection somewhere else, not in the code shown.

Comment: If you'd like to share a bit more code, lesv (at) gXXgle.com

Answer (score 1):

We have updated examples for interacting with Cloud Bigtable from Google App Engine Flex and Standard using Java 8 here:

- https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine-java8/bigtable
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/java/gae-flexible-helloworld